# Jquery UI Datepicker beforeShowDay bug with blocking an array of dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using [Davidwalsh's method](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days) for blocking out specific dates on the datepicker calender, but on my production server certain dates in the array aren't being blocked off, so I tried to do a clean replicate of the code, and discovered the similar discrepancies in the results.

[This is the JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/winterain/6E6KS/1/)

Can someone kindly point out something I'm missing here ?

For some reason, 1 November is blocked out, and 4th nov is not being blocked out.

On my production server's situation, we tried to block out 2 dates in december, but they fail to get disabled. Dates from the current month get blocked fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var cdates = new Array();
        cdates = ['2012-11-04','2012-11-12','2012-12-03','2012-12-12','2012-12-18','2012-12-20'];

        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: check_closed
        }); 

        function check_closed(date)
        {               var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

            for (i = 0; i < cdates.length; i++) {
                if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,cdates) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
                    console.log('bad:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y + ' / ' + cdates[i]);
                  return [false,''];
                }
                    console.log('good:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y);
                return [true,''];    
            }                
        }
    });​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not padding day with a 0. For example, for the 1st of the month:

```
d = date.getDate(); // => 1 and for adequate comparison needs to be 01
```

The solution:

```
d = date.getDate();
if( d < 10 ) { d = "0" + d; }
```

That is why 4th of November is not disable, because var m = "2012-11-4" and the only value that exists in the array is "2012-11-04.

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/KYzaR/8/

Comment: My solution was added a if(d<10) { d = '0'+d; }

Comment: @Winterain You are absolutely right. Thanks for that, I have amended the answer. Going to upvote you :)